# How to uninstall a rpm that I checkinstalled?

Tags: linux, vim, fedora, yum, checkinstall

I just built `vim` with `checkinstall` running:

`[root@localhost vim]# checkinstall -R -y --fstrans=no`

I see there is a rpm created there :

```
[root@localhost vim]# ls /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/
checkinstall-20141012-1.x86_64.rpm  vim-20141012-1.x86_64.rpm
```

vim works fine...

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 12 2014 16:19:20)
Included patches: 1-475
Compiled by statquant
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +clipboard       +cursorshape     +extra_search    -hangul_input    +listcmds        -mouse_gpm       -mzscheme        +python3/dyn     +startuptime     +termresponse    +viminfo         +xsmp_interact
+arabic          +cmdline_compl   +dialog_con_gui  +farsi           +iconv           +localmap        -mouse_jsbterm   +netbeans_intg   +quickfix        +statusline      +textobjects     +vreplace        +xterm_clipboard
+autocmd         +cmdline_hist    +diff            +file_in_path    +insert_expand   +lua             +mouse_netterm   +path_extra      +reltime         -sun_workshop    +title           +wildignore      -xterm_save
+balloon_eval    +cmdline_info    +digraphs        +find_in_path    +jumplist        +menu            +mouse_sgr       +perl            +rightleft       +syntax          +toolbar         +wildmenu        +xpm
+browse          +comments        +dnd             +float           +keymap          +mksession       -mouse_sysmouse  +persistent_undo +ruby            +tag_binary      +user_commands   +windows
++builtin_terms  +conceal         -ebcdic          +folding         +langmap         +modify_fname    +mouse_urxvt     +postscript      +scrollbind      +tag_old_static  +vertsplit       +writebackup
+byte_offset     +cryptv          +emacs_tags      -footer          +libcall         +mouse           +mouse_xterm     +printer         +signs           -tag_any_white   +virtualedit     +X11
+cindent         +cscope          +eval            +fork()          +linebreak       +mouseshape      +multi_byte      +profile         +smartindent     +tcl             +visual          -xfontset
+clientserver    +cursorbind      +ex_extra        +gettext         +lispindent      +mouse_dec       +multi_lang      +python/dyn      -sniff           +terminfo        +visualextra     +xim
```

For some reason I cannot uninstall it...

```
[root@localhost vim]# rpm -e /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/vim-20141012-1.x86_64.rpm
error: package /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/vim-20141012-1.x86_64.rpm is not installed
[root@localhost vim]# rpm -e vim-20141012-1.x86_64
error: package vim-20141012-1.x86_64 is not installed
[root@localhost vim]# rpm -e vim
error: package vim is not installed
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`rpm -e` doesn't take a fullpath as an argument, just the package name:

```
rpm -e vim-20141012-1.x86_64
```

Or even:

```
rpm -e vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Install it again (using rpm) and uninstall it again the same way.